# apache Mob pagespeed and cache

Tags: regex, apache, caching, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I'm using google's mob-pagespeed on my apache website 
https://he.mypen.net/

It's optimize my css and js files, for example:
https://he.mypen.net/scripts/choose.js,qver=67.pagespeed.jm.ahUFvaSUYk.js
instead of https://he.mypen.net/scripts/choose.js?ver=67

And it also use:
https://he.mypen.net/styles,_home.css,qver==10+user_baright.css,qver==42.pagespeed.cc.ekyP6lfGgI.css

The problem that those files cache only for 5 minutes. For some reason, this header doesnt work on them.

```
<filesMatch "\\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|eot|svg|woff|ttf)$">
  Header set Cache-control "max-age=31535000 public"
</filesMatch>
```

Is this because the filesMatch doesnt apply to those files? Or it's because they are mob-pagespeed generated files?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using custom rules, you should follow the built-in procedure to set the cache lifetime:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#implicit_cache_ttl